# Show active Element in TMENU always first (TYPO3)

Tags: html, css, typo3, typoscript

I've created a nice HTML Template which i am currently trying to integrate into my TYPO3 instance.

Like always I did things not the easy way : ) and now I am wondering if there is a solution for what I've already wrote in the Title:

Is there a way to always start with the current active element in a menu?

Thanks for your help, really appreciate it!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a method to do that with one menu. My idea would be to use two menus: The first one renders only the active item, the second one only the normal items. To do so, use `doNotShowLink` on the unwanted menu items. Afterwards, combine the menus into one element using a COA. Here's some TS, for the first menu level:

```
lib.menu = COA
lib.menu {
 wrap = <ol class="menu">|</ol>

  1 = HMENU
  1 {

    1 = TMENU
    1 {

      NO.doNotShowLink = 1

      ACT = 1
      ACT {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
      }
    }
  }

  2 = HMENU
  2 {

    1 = TMENU
    1 {

      NO = 1
      NO {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li class="normal">|</li>
      }

      ACT = 1
      ACT.doNotShowLink = 1
    }
  }
}
```

By using some clever copying, it should be possible to keep the maintainance efforts to a minimum, even when having two menus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i did something similuar - without COA. It really seems there's no All-in-1 solution.